# Construct smooth mapping $f: B^{n + 1} \to S^n$ with two singularities at which $f$ has degree $+/- 1$.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm currently working through a paper by Pjotr Hajlasz who wants to show that

> For smooth manifolds $M,N$, if $\pi_{[p]}(N) \neq 0$ and $1 \leq p < n = \dim M$, then the smooth mappings $C^\infty(M,N)$ are not dense in $W^{1,p}(M,N)$.

In his proof he asserts that

> "It is easy to construct a smooth mapping $f: B^{[p]+1} \to S^{[p]}$ with two singularities such that $f$ restricted to small spheres centered at the singularities have degree +1 and -1 respectively."

How would one go about to construct or at least think about such smooth mapping?

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Cool result!${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $B^{n+1}\setminus\{p,q\}\cong S^n\times(0,1)$, and define your map $f\colon S^n\times(0,1)\to S^n$ to just be projection onto the first factor.

Comment: "to just be projection" sounds bad. "to be the projection", perhaps?

Comment: @Pedro: Methinks a non-native English speaker shouldn't necessarily correct a native speaker. :) It sounds just peachy to me.

Comment: @TedShifrin The word "just" seems superfluous: "define X to just be Y" means "define X to be Y". What purpose does the word "just" serve?

Comment: Ah, @Pedro, I concur that we should omit "just." I thought you were insisting on "the." (With the "just," I would put it before "to," anyhow.)

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Could you explain why the mapping $f$ then has the desired property?

Comment: @Nhat: Spherical links of the singularities are just cross sections $S^n\times \{\epsilon\}$, so the restriction of the map to those links is the natural diffeomorphism $S^n\times \{\epsilon\}\to S^n$, which is a $\pm 1$ degree map. In fact, the way you induce orientations, it will be $+1$ at one singularity and $-1$ at the other.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: the "just" here was to indicate that it is an elementary construction.